# Remote Desktop Software Recommendations

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control

we need remote desktop software for our company. We already search in the internet but we cant find it. Software should contain them:

- easy to use(setup and other stuff)
- should **not request permission** from the computer to be connected
- connection requirements must be just ip / windows username and passwords
- trail version(for test)

We will wait for your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this meant for use in local network or over internet? Also, for what client and server OSs?

Comment: "`should not request permission from the computer to be connected`" is a ***major*** security flaw

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Only if it don't ask for a password either. Pretty much all remote desktop software do this, without asking on the remote computer, for a fully unattended server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RealVnc](https://www.realvnc.com/) does all what you want. It can be set up in server-less mode, and it can be installed even as a windows service, making it running even on a login screen.

Easy setup: well, that is relative. It has a GUI installer where you can click everything, but you need to understand which option exactly what means. Check also the firewall settings, possibly you need to allow the incoming tcp port 5900 manually.

It can be password-less (insecure), use a pre-defined password and possibly also other authentication methods exist.

RealVnc istself is not opensource, but the VNC protocol is; which results that numerous client and server versions of the protocol are also available (in Linux environment, I use [x11vnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11vnc) for the server and [xtigervnc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/Xtigervnc.1.html) for the client side).

The disadvantages:

- it lacks sound support (you can transmit also the sound channels with [pulseaudio](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio))
- not all client work with all servers, try before productive usage
- client-side bitmap caching is sometimes buggy, resulting slow scrolling. This can be solved by a correctly chosen, and correctly configured client/server side.

Answer (score 1):

TEAMVIEWER meets all your needs, you can use it on LAN and Internet. The menu is very, very simple and clear. There is also a trial version. https://www.teamviewer.com/de/produkte/teamviewer/

Answer (score 0):

You can use UltraViewer that wont need permission from user. It will just need a user id and password which that can set permanently from user panel.
also you can use TeamViewer that has the same features...

I am working in a company named [ParastehDigital](https://parasteh.ir) which we use [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) for remote connection to our users but it required an accept button for privilege connection from user.
It's really easy to use and don't need other stuff like password or etc. all you need is just an id number of that user when you want to connect to it.

If you care about security I recommend you to use AnyDesk cause it will not let the person who connect to you access all of your system or syslock your windows if you are using windows 7....

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your the advice. problem is, our devices aren't connected to the internet they connect with just local(for securty and privacy) and these programs need to connect internet and give connection information or required accept. we found DameWare and UltraVNC but, does not meet all requests. 
thanks anyway, I wish you a good day